# Dynamics CRM 2015 update data

Tags: import, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

Exported data from CRM2015, updated one field in spreadsheet that needs updating, resaved as Excel 2003 xml format.

Struggling to see how to import back in to get it to update existing contact using the 3 fields the export from CRM included.

All it does is attempt to create new records.

Answer (score 1):

Do not save it as Excel 2003 XML format if you want to re-import the file. 2003 XML-files trigger the old-school import process, where it is not possible to update existing records (but on the other hand you have more options for mapping data).

Instead you should simply re-import the original .xlsx-file. This will automatically update the existing records in CRM based on the information in the first three hidden columns.